# found invokx in this source code

Tags: masm32

I'm very new to masm.

Was trying to read this source code I found online and I came about invokx,
which is not invoke. Can't find anything on it around, strange, can anybody explain? can it be just a typo?

code snippet here

```
invoke  Install
invoke  EnumProcs
invokx  _ExitProcess, 0
```

and another snippet too in some other part of the code

```
@nomore:
;; Dedstroy handle
invokx  _CloseHandle[ebx], hSnapshot
```

any help will be much appreciated , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your code snippets, it's probably the [macro defined here](https://github.com/nyx0/Tinba/blob/master/source/macro.inc#L208).

As the code is from the Tinba banking trojan, there's [this article](https://hackmag.com/malware/the-smallest-trojan-of-modern-age/) that talks about it:

> ‘GetBaseDelta’ and ‘invokx’ are macros predefined in the code. As its
>   name suggests, the first one calculates the delta offset and puts the
>   result in ‘ebx’ register [...] The second macro calls an API function
>   based on the contents of ‘ebx’ register (i.e. by taking into account
>   the same delta offset).

It seems that `invokx` can also work like the standard `invoke`.